# Setting \SIrange and units in parentheses

Tags: siunitx

I need to set a range with units in parentheses, nevertheless once I use `\SIrange` I can't set the left and right parenthesis as used in a normal text.

I tried with `\SIrange[range-units = brackets]{2}{5}{wt.\%}` but this options put only the number in parenthesis. Here is the example:

concentration (2-5 wt.%) and

Many thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Are you after just `(\SIrange[range-units = single]{2}{5}{wt.\%} )`?